# copy row values based on result from isin() in pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes:

```
df_a = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4],'B':[4,5,6,7],'ID':['a','b','c','d']})
df_a    
   A  B ID
0  1  4  a
1  2  5  b 
2  3  6  c
3  4  7  d
df_b = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'ID':['b','a','c']})
df_b['CopyB'] = ""
    A   ID  CopyB
0   1   b   
1   2   a   
2   3   c
```

Now I want to match ID columns in both the dataframes and upon a successful match, I want to copy respective value of B from df_a to df_b['CopyB']. I tried `df_b.loc[df_b['ID'].isin(df_a['ID']),'Copy']= df_a['B]`
but that is not correct. Then I tried comparing the ID using '==' but got an error  since the length of the ID series is not equal. Any help? Sorry if it is a very trivial query.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `merge`

```
In [247]: df_b.merge(df_a, on=['ID'])
Out[247]:
   A_x ID  A_y  B
0    1  b    2  5
1    2  a    1  4
2    3  c    3  6

In [248]: df_b.merge(df_a, on=['ID'])[['A_x', 'ID', 'B']].rename(columns={'A_x': 'A'})
Out[248]:
   A ID  B
0  1  b  5
1  2  a  4
2  3  c  6
```

Comment: Thanks John. It really helped.

Answer (score 1):

use `join`

```
df_b.join(df_a.set_index('ID').B, on='ID')

   A ID  B
0  1  b  5
1  2  a  4
2  3  c  6
```

---

`join` works on indices.  So I set the index of `df_a` to be the `ID` column and access the `B` column so that `df_a.set_index('ID').B` is a series with the column I want to add as values and the merge column as the index.  Then I use `join`.  I wouldn't have to specify an `on` parameter if `ID` was the index of `df_b` but it isn't, so I do.

Comment: @sacmax don't forget to mark it as the answer with the green check.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the ID column as a common index for both dataframes you can easily add the column:

```
df_a = df_a.set_index('ID')
df_b = db_b.set_index('ID')

df_b['Copy B'] = df_a['B']
```